# Auth create,what I need to do next?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have login feature in my app.My app connect to open API,its succesfull request and I have OK,and code==200.I need to get list of this user following channels.But when I creating authentification session,what can I do?I insert part of my code,in this part,when I check **"if(response.isSuccessful())"** 
can I start new activity and get the user video or not?Does this session saving or something like this?

```
Call<SignInResults> call = videoApi.insertUser(username_value,password_value);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SignInResults>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SignInResults> call, Response<SignInResults> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                SignInResults results = response.body();
                Log.d("Response ==>> ", new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(results));
            }
            else {
                // handle error
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SignInResults> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your next logical step of progression could be to save the result(`SignInResults`),which I guess would be some sort of api key or token in `[SharedPreferences][1]` so all other API-contacting methods in the future use that as your authentication mechanism.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("api_key", results.api_key);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: I cant get data(
SignInResults results = response.body(); is null